# Create/Get TableMapping Map to send to SQLiteAsyncConnection.DeleteAll()

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

Am attempting to delete all items from a sqlite database table accessed via nuget package sqlite-net-pcl(1.5.166-beta) for Xamarin.forms.

The method DeleteAllAsync, according to Visual Studio's code completion menu, 
takes a 'TableMapping Map' Can you help me find out what a 'TableMapping Map' is in this case?

Where could I find the documentation for the sqlite-net-pcl nuget package? There is no project page listed for it on nuget.

The code snippet below gives context and an incorrect call of DeleteAllAsync

```cs
public class ItemDb
{
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

    public ItemDb(string dbPath)
    {
        database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        database.CreateTableAsync<Item>().Wait();
    } 
    internal void DeleteAll()
    {
        database.DeleteAllAsync(database.Table<Item>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to specify the `Type` to use `DeleteAllAsync`, and it will remove all items from the table.

```
internal async Task DeleteAll()
{
    await database.DeleteAllAsync<Item>();
}
```

`DeleteAllAsync` is new in sqlite-net-pcl v1.5, and v1.5 is still in pre-release. The official documentation is here, and it will likely be updated to include `DeleteAllAsync` once v1.5 is promoted to stable:
https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/wiki

**Faster Method**

A faster way to delete all items in a table is to drop the table and re-create it (assuming the tables has many items).

```
internal async Task DeleteAll()
{
    await database.DropTableAsync<Item>();
    await database.CreateTableAsync<Item>();
}
```

**Complete Example**

Here is a complete example that helps improve performance and avoid multithreading problems.

```cs
public class ItemDb
{
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;
    readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    public ItemDb(string dbPath)
    {
        database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
    } 

    internal async Task DeleteAllItems()
    {    
        await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        await Initialize<Item>().ConfigureAwait(false);

        try
        {
            await database.DropTableAsync<Item>().ConfigureAwait(false);
            await database.CreateTableAsync<Item>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
    }

    async Task Initialize<T>()
    {
        if (!DatabaseConnection.TableMappings.Any(x => x.MappedType.Name == typeof(T).Name))
        {
            await DatabaseConnection.EnableWriteAheadLoggingAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            await DatabaseConnection.CreateTablesAsync(CreateFlags.None, typeof(T)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great! You've gone over and above by providing a thread-safer option as well as the simple answer.

Comment: `Initialize()` is not thread-safe. Calling it should be after waiting on the semaphore. `await Initialize().ConfigureAwait(false);` should be after `await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`